# Component not updating on redux state change

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

As the title says my component, which is connected to the redux store with the `connect` function is not triggering an update for a state change for a particular case while working well for other cases.

The variable in the state which is being modified has the following structure

```
state: {
  billDetails: {
    productType1: {...},
    productType2: {...},          
    productType3: {...},
    productType4: {
      accountId1 : [
        {invoiceNo:1, isChecked: true},
        {invoiceNo:2, isChecked: false}  
      ],
      accountId2: [...]
    }
  }
}
```

i am trying to change the falue of ischecked from a reducer which is successfully happening as i can see it changing in the react-native debugger, however the component itself is not getting updated.

here is the code to my reducer code for that particular case

```
{
  const { accountId, invoiceNo, isChecked } = action.payload;
  const billDetails = result(state.billDetail, `${action.payload.productType}.${accountId}`, []);
  const billDetailsModified = billDetails.map((bill) => {
    if (bill.invoiceNo === invoiceNo) {
      bill.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
    return bill;
  });
  const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
  newState.billDetail[action.payload.productType][accountId] = billDetailsModified;
  return newState;
}
```

the component is connected to the `billdetails` object in the `mapStateToProps` function using `billDetail: result(state, 'billUsage.billDetail', {})`

Comment: Have you debugged your redux state to ensure that reducer is doing the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.assign copies property value, so object references are copied, so state.billDetail and newState.billDetail refer to same object. Therefore, you are mutating the original state, which makes the state to be `not updating`.